# How do I find or earn higher level weapons in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Someone gave me a Spectrum Sword (Attack of 38k and 15 properties with it). I've seen other people with similarly awesome weapons and armor like this, so I'm wondering can I earn or find items like these?

Answer (score 4):

There are no legitimate items with stats like that.  The weapon you were given (and the similar ones you've seen on other people) is the result of someone hacking their game to make overpowered items.  The standard ways for getting better weapons in Diablo 3 are either to find it by fighting high level monsters, or using the crafting system.